# What is "this" in global scope when using a JScript component template

Tags: templating, 2011-sp1, javascript

In classic ASP this works:

```
<%
Response.write ( typeof this); //object

varInGlobalScope = 1;

Response.write( varInGlobalScope ); //1
Response.write( this.varInGlobalScope ); //1

this.varInGlobalScope = 2;

Response.write( varInGlobalScope ); //2
Response.write( this.varInGlobalScope ); //2
%>
```

In a Tridion component template it fails:

```
[%
writeOut( typeof this ); //object

varInGlobalScope = 1;

writeOut( varInGlobalScope ); //1
writeOut( this.varInGlobalScope ); //nothing

this.varInGlobalScope = 2; //fails with the following error
//Error 438 occurred while rendering the Component Presentation (Test): Object doesn't support this property or method (source: this.varInGlobalScope = 2;).
//Content Manager StackTrace: UtilitiesPublish.RenderComponentPresentation ComponentPresentation.Render Component.Render Request.Render 
%]
```

Comment: What Tridion version are you using these JScript Templates on?

Comment: This is the info from our installation: SDL Tridion 2011, Content Manager Explorer - Build 6.1.0.55920, Content Manager - Build 6.1.0.998, Update Version - Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - 2

Comment: Why are you wondering what "this" is exactly? Apparently in classis ASP it allows you to do the same thing as you could do without using "this.", but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use JavaScript in both "Classic" ASP and in "Classic" Tridion templates, these technologies are very different. I don't remember much about classic ASP, but I don't think the `this` keyword was used very much at all.

In JavaScript, `this` is an important feature of the language, and allows you to refer to various things, but mostly the function that's currently executing. The details are gnarly, but [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) would be a good start.

In practice, when you host a JavaScript engine such as JScript, there's some scope for wiring up your own objects to be available to the script. In a Tridion legacy component template, for example, the component presentation is available to be used. There may be ways make your own object become `this` in the global scope, and it seems that perhaps Classic ASP did this. You could look for more details in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9d4xf28(v=vs.85).aspx). If the programmer wiring up the script hosting doesn't do anything about `this`, you might speculate that it's an empty dictionary, or something else, but without the code, it's hard to know.

But really - there is no reason in the world why you should expect to transfer a little-used technique from ASP to a Tridion template and have it work. That is a fundamental misunderstanding of the technology you are dealing with. The two things are not the same, and you can't expect them to behave the same.

Comment: The premise that "ASP and JavaScript are very different languages" is incorrect. ASP is not a language, it's an engine. ASP pages can be written using both VBScript and JScript. Comparing ASP to JScript/Javascript is meaningless. Tridion 2011 allows component templates to be written in both VBScript and JScript. The JScript implementation in Tridion appears to function differently to the JScript implementation in ASP. Disclosure: I'm on Stephens team.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Kevin. The original question didn't make clear that JScript was used in the ASP too. To be honest, ASP is so long ago that I could only remember the vbscript version until you reminded me. My fundamental point still remains, however, and that is that the technologies aren't the same and it's not reasonable to expect them to have the same characteristics. I've updated my answer.